# Using Sendkeys to press a space in Jscript

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have this line in my batch file:

```
kbd(['{RIGHT}','{RIGHT}', '{TAB}', '{ENTER}','{SPACE}', '%s']);
```

It runs everything fine until the very end. It will not press the space button. I need to press the space button to uncheck a checkbox.

Comment: How about a little more information. Are you saying you have a console program named kbd.exe and it takes arguments for execution but will not execute all the arguments?

Comment: Yes, as the question states it runs the command great until it reaches the space command which it will not press.

Comment: This is definitely not a [tag:batch-file]! Read the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info)!

Comment: I think you meant to use the [autohotkey] tag instead of the [batch-file] tag; like aschipfl said, what you posted isn't valid batch.

Comment: Since you decided to delete your other question I will post here.  If you just need to know where java is installed you can run this command: `where /r "C:Program Files (x86)\java" javaw.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. If using the kbd command you want to press a space you do not use {SPACE} you use ' '. SO it would look like this:

```
kbd(['{RIGHT}','{RIGHT}', '{TAB}', '{ENTER}','{SPACE}', '%s']);
```

To

```
kbd(['{RIGHT}','{RIGHT}', '{TAB}', '{ENTER}',' ', '%s']);
```